# For FCM, when receiving notification app crashed, error as Unable to instantiate receiver FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

For FCM, when receiving notification app gets crashed and getting an error as java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"

```
gradle dependencies: project level 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'

gradle dependencies: app level
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends 
FirebaseInstanceIdService  {
String refreshedToken="";
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("Firebase", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
}




public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
{

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d("messaging", "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
//        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("notify message",remoteMessage.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: Are you getting this issue only for Oreo device or all devices with other versions?

Comment: getting this issue for all android versions

Comment: Hope you have added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in app level gradle` file as the last statement. Like: http://prntscr.com/ndqj65

Comment: I need to clarify that right now app is not getting crashed but not even understanding notification is received or not because onMessageReceived() is not getting called

Comment: yes that plugin is added